# Resize multiple comments to fixed size

Tags: excel, comments, vba

I've created a excel sheet to replicate a desk plan of an office, using comment display boxes `filled with picture` to display mugshots on mouse-overs.

I painstakingly sized them to `4.5cm x 4cm` via format object. But since some minor alterations the sizing had changed.

I found that using VBA people have done a mass size change for a 'Autofit', thought I could tailor it to a fixed size to save me time.

This is what I have, `*4.5cm x 4cm*` being the area in question, unless it's all in need of change, help?

```
Sub FitComments()
    Dim xComment As Comment
    For Each xComment In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments
        xComment.Shape.TextFrame.Size = * 4.5cm x 4cm *
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the sizing properties of the code look like when you record the action?

Comment: The `Shape.TextFrame`  doesn't have the property `.Size`. If you record a macro like @Jeeped mentioned, you will come to know how the size can be set using `ScaleWidth` and `ScaleHeight`

Comment: While you are at it, I would be tempted to changed teh comment boxes to another sort of shape  as I've found comments seem to randomly resize and move themselves (I think when freeze panes is used - but I've never got to the bottom of it).

Comment: I'm pretty fresh at this, I'm not overly familiar with Marcos. I shall experiment shortly. - Was hopping it would be a simple language/code change to the above. Thanks

Comment: Here's a macro recording of me changing a cell comment size.

'
    Range("L9").Select
    Range("L9").Comment.Text Text:=""
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SizeComments()
    Dim cmt As Comment

    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With cmt.Shape
            .ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        End With
    Next cmt
End Sub
```

I found and ran this code, this seems to double the current size of all comments I have, which works quite well for the time being, but I'm unable to set them to a specific size annoyingly and with the random distortion to the sizes the ratio will get warped.